# Can a GNOME application be automated? How?

Tags: linux, user-interface, automation, gnome

Can a GNOME application be automated? I.e., can I programatically interact with its user inteface?

How?

Comment: For what purposes you are looking at automation? I was looking at the answers are both of them being quite valid: Dogtail if it's more towards GUI testing; and probably DBus if you want to programmatically interact with a GUI app from your own app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While specifically designed to test GUIs, [dogtail](https://github.com/vhumpa/dogtail) provides the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know much about it, try looking into ATK. I know there was a project a while back called facade (part of FVWM?) that used ATK to figure out the logical elements of an application and interact with and modify them.

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at DBus.