# running commands in an external gnome-terminal using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am trying to execute commands using communicate in the terminal that i spawned.

```
 sitecreate_proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess)
 out = sitecreate_proc.communicate("pwd")
 print out
```

the "out" variable is always empty.
Displaying the terminal is necessary.

Comment: As I remember communicate return a tuple, `communicate() returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).  so you can't user communicate("pwd"). gnome-terminal returns, then try to get that result, by `sitecreate_proc.communicate()[0]` for stroutdate, or `sitecreate_proc.communicate()[0]` for stderrdata

Comment: @darvark, Yes, you're right. even if i use communicate("pwd")[0] it gives me nothing.

Comment: @darvark, Yes please post the answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a GNOME application be automated? How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006193/can-a-gnome-application-be-automated-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` is a graphical application and as one, [likely doesn't use its own standard streams that it got from the parent process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#GUIs).

You need to run console applications instead to communicate with them -

- either the commands themselves:

  ```
  >>> subprocess.check_output("pwd")
  '/c/Users/Ivan\n'
  ```
- or an *interactive shell command*, then send input to it and receive responses as per [Interacting with bash from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673730/interacting-with-bash-from-python)

---

If you just need to output stream data to the same console that `python` is using, you can simply write out their data as you're getting it - either [automatically with `tee`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python), or by hand at appropriate moments.

---

If, instead, you need to launch an independent terminal emulator window on a desktop and interact with it via IPC, that's another matter entirely - namely, [UI automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006193/can-a-gnome-application-be-automated-how), and has nothing to do with standard console streams.

[The most common way for that in Linux is D-Bus](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10455) (there are other options outlined on the previous link). Ppl report however (as of 2012) [that `gnome-terminal` doesn't support D-bus and you have to jump through hoops to interact with it](https://superuser.com/questions/94930/gnome-terminal-new-tab-dbus). There is [an article on controlling `konsole` via D-Bus](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/start-and-control-konsole-dbus) though.

Comment: Displaying the terminal is necessary for my project. That is why i didn't directly run the commands. Sorry for the Misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember communicate return a tuple,

> communicate() returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata)

. so you can't user communicate("pwd"). gnome-terminal returns, then try to get that result, by `sitecreate_proc.communicate()[0]` for stroutdate, or `sitecreate_proc.communicate()[0]` for stderrdata

Comment: i can't undersatand what you want to say(Sorry for that). Can you post a code sample?

Comment: `sitecreate_proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal'],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 out = sitecreate_proc.communicate()[0]` will return nothing as ivan_pozdeev wrote. eventualy you can try to get bash exit status `$?`, and if it's equal to 0 then success, in other case error. More details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631624/how-to-get-exit-code-when-using-python-subprocess-communicate-method